# How to find the probability density function of a function of two random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I am trying to figure out how I can determine the PDF of a random variable Y that is itself a function of two other random variables A and B.

In this example, A ~ N(0,1) and B ~ Bernoulli (p = 0.5). Both variables are independent and we define the random variable Y as follows:

[image]

I'm lost as to where to start so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like Y ~ N(0,1).  Try to get the distribution function  by direct calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you say $$P(Y<y) = P(Y<y\mid B=0)P(B=0) + P(Y<y\mid B=1)P(B=1)$$
and simplify these terms?

Comment: Thanks! I think you're correct but I'm curious what made you think to use the CDF and the total probability theorem to eventually derive the PDF? I think there is a fundamental gap somewhere in my knowledge that I'd like to identify and fill.

Comment: Knowing the CDF is often essentially equivalent to knowing the PDF. And quite often the CDF is easier to work with.